How to add horizontal spacing to vertical scrollbar in CSS?
Pretty basic use case but unfortunately I haven't found a working solution yet:
I am writing a UI using CSS/Html, and I simply would like to add some horizontal space between the vertical scroll-bar and the right-margin.
How do I achieve that ? Here is how my code looks now. As you can see I have tried using box-sizing + padding trick but this does not do it unfortunately.
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      margin-right: 20px; /* This does not work, but offsetting with padding will */
      width: 8px;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color:  #201F24;
      border-radius: 8px;
      border: 3px solid transparent;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background-color: transparent;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
      background-color: #2B292F;
  }

  #container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      padding-right: 20px; /* Adjust to create the space between scrollbar and the right side */
      box-sizing: content-box; /* Ensure padding doesn't affect scroll area */
  }

https://jsfiddle.net/rtobgy5h/4/
What is missing here ?
(This is what I am trying to achieve. See the yellow bar not being stuck to the right edge)


Try making padding-right a negative value

Not completly clear for what scrollbar you want to achive it for body scrollbar or for the container scrollbar because of your layout you have currently both of them. Try this and just adjust the container size or configure scroll for body.
   ::-webkit-scrollbar { /* This does not work, but offsetting with padding will */
      width: 8px;
   }

   ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
       background-color:  red;
       border-radius: 8px;
   }

   ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
       background-color: green;
   }


   #container {
       width: 100%;
       height: 92vh;
       overflow-y: scroll;
   }

